# Is this basic OAuth Owin authentication process in MVC.net is safe enough (with Google and Facebook)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, owin

I implemented a basic owin OAuth authentication process (with Google and Facebook), but I'm a little worried questioning if the "login info" got in the External LoginCallback is safe enough to be use, do I have to do anything else ?  Here the "ending" AccountController code, but the main thing have been made while following this paterne/example :

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Apr/29/Adding-minimal-OWIN-Identity-Authentication-to-an-Existing-ASPNET-MVC-Application#MinimalCodeSummary

Thanks!

```
private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";
internal class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
{
    public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
        : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
    {
    }

    public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
    {
        LoginProvider = provider;
        RedirectUri = redirectUri;
        UserId = userId;
    }

    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
        if (UserId != null)
        {
            properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
        }
        context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
    }
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    ChallengeResult r = new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Users", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    return r;
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    if (returnUrl == null) returnUrl = string.Empty;  // just to reduce validation below...

    // Get login info
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        // if none, return to login page
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
    else
    {
        // is this login info safe and thrustable to create or login the user
        string username = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider + "_ " + loginInfo.Login.ProviderKey;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The authentication methods that Google and Facebook implement are pretty secure, but you have to remember that your `ExternalLogin` and `ExternalLoginCallback` are allowing anonymous calls, which means any one can call them.

So it could be a good idea to check for an AntiForgery token on `ExternalLogin`. Decorate it with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`. See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery).

On your `ExternalLoginCallback` you could add a validation to check that the request is coming from a known url, like Google's or Facebook's url. If it's not, raise and error.

And of course on production always use https.